# Printing task names when running ansible adhoc commands

Tags: ansible

I need to run some roles from command line for testing and sometimes I have some adhoc tasks to apply. So I use `ansible` to run the role. For example:

```
$ ansible all -i 192.168.1.123,  -m include_role -a"name=myrole" -e '@role.json'
```

This works fine and prints out a lot of information but it does not print task `-name:` text. What I mean is the text which is normally printed by `ansible-playbook` like this:

```
TASK [Do this and that...]
```

But `ansible` does not print this. Without this information, sometimes it is difficult to tell where ansible is exactly. If a task fails, it is difficult to figure out which task failed...

Is there a way to run roles in adhoc fashion and also have more information about exactly which task is running?

Answer (score 0):

No, the adhoc ansible script can't print that. Workaround is creating a simple playbook:

```
---

- hosts: "{{ myhost }}"
  tasks:

  - import_role:
      name: "{{ myrole }}"
```

Run with:

```
ansible-playbook /path/roletest.yml -e 'myrole=coolrole myhost=awesomehost' -e '@role.json'
```

Comment: This is what I came up with as workaround also but what about inventory? If host is given as variable. I need to give `-i myhost,` again on command line or it says `provided hosts list is empty` Isn't it better if `-hosts: all` is used with `-i myhost` from command line only? Then you need 1 variable.